# Allow user input in second command in bash pipe

Tags: bash, pipe

I'm looking for how I might allow user input in a second command in a bash statement and I'm not sure how to go about it. I'd like to be able to provide a one-liner for someone to be able to install my application, but part of that application process requires asking some questions.

The current script setup looks like:

```
curl <url/to/bootstrap.sh> | bash
```

and then boostrap.sh does:

```
if [ $UID -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "This script requires root to run. Restarting the script under root."
    exec sudo $0 "$@"
    exit $?
fi
git clone <url_to_repo> /usr/local/repo/
bash /usr/local/repo/.setup/install_system.sh
```

which in turn calls a python3 script that asks for `input`.

I know that the the `curl` in the first line is using stdin and so that might make what I'm asking impossible and that it has to be two lines to ever work:

```
wget <url/to/boostrap.sh>
bash bootstrap.sh
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can restructure your script to run this way:

```
bash -c "$(curl -s http://0.0.0.0//test.bash 2>/dev/null)"
foo
wololo:a
a
```

My test.bash is really just

```
#!/bin/bash
echo foo
python -c 'x = raw_input("wololo:");print(x)'`
```

To demonstrate that stdin can be read from in this way. Sure it creates a subshell to take care of curl but it allows you to keep reading from stdin as well.